# Display toast after startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, toast

I am trying to display a toast message after the user gets to the main intent.

I try to accomplish that by doing this by the code below but with no success:

On the second activity(MapsActivity) I did:

```
    public void userLocationIsNull(){
    
        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1010);

    }
```

And on the first activity(MainActivity) I did:

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
            if (requestCode == 1010) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "System could find your location,please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
}
```

The intent is working,but the Toast is'nt showing,glad to hear your thoughts,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check into the use of `onActivityResult()` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Your `onActivityResult()` will be called in the activity in which you create the intent itself(in this case your MapsActivity) and not in any other Activity (here MainActivity).

***Update***

Ok so once you have used this method correctly, try this inside your if statement for requestCode

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
  // your toast here 
}
else{
  // the Activity result is null, and so your 'if' statement is not working
}
```

Tell me if this helps or not

Comment: Hey,thanks for your replay,I tried called onActivityResult in MapsActivity the same way,but the toast isn't showing..

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using

```
 Toast.makeText(this, "System could find your location,please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

try :

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "System could find your location,please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```